# Бессоюзное сложное предложение

Tags: синтаксис

*Действовать будем так: сначала отыщем лодку, потом поплывём на другой берег.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему данное предложение будет являться сложным и где здесь вторая грамматическая основа?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь даже три предложения. Предикативные основы - *будем действовать, отыщем, поплывём*.  **Это спорный вопрос.**
Валгина считает:

> Предложения с несколькими глагольными сказуемыми являют собой
>   переходный, промежуточный тип между простым и сложным предложением.
>   Переходные типы не нарушают общей классификационной схемы, а лишь
>   подчеркивают существование «синтаксически не вполне
>   дифференцированных» предложений, а последнее только подтверждает
>   системный характер синтаксического строя: «Наличие перекрещивающихся
>   связей и взаимозависимостей при разной степени охвата этих связей
>   является наиболее существенным для системности языка, для его
>   целостности».
>
> Выявление существенных свойств подлежащего и сказуемого
>   как структурных элементов предикативной основы предложения позволяет
>   квалифицировать синтаксические конструкции с двумя или несколькими
>   главными членами следующим образом.
>
> Предложения с несколькими
>   подлежащими, объединенными одним сказуемым, являются простыми
>   предложениями с однородными членами: Жара и засуха стояли более трех
>   недель (Л. Т.); Вздохи и зеванье старухи, мерное дыхание спавшей бабы,
>   сумерки избы и шум дождя за окном располагали ко сну (Ч.).
>
> Объединение главных членов в форме номинативных
>   предложений представляет собой предложение сложное: Осинник зябкий, да
>   речушка узкая, да синий бор, да желтые поля (Сурк.); Дождь и ветер
>   (Шол.).
>
> Однако предложение является простым, если имеется общее 
>   определение: Красивые города и пригороды.
>
> Предложения с разными типами
>   неглагольных сказуемых — это простые предложения с однородными
>   членами: Он любим и уважаем как славный товарищ и храбрый солдат (П.);
>   Море было спокойно, черно и густо, как масло (М. Г.); Ночь была
>   темная, свежая и безветренная (Л. Т.). Объединяющим элементом в таких
>   построениях обычно выступает связка.
>
> В качестве однородных в составе
>   простого предложения могут выступать и части глагольного сказуемого
>   (при единой, общей связке): В дороге я почувствовал, что мной
>   овладевает нетерпение. Хотелось скорее добраться до конторы, скорее
>   взять телефонную трубку, скорее услышать знакомый Долин голос (Сол.).
>
> Предложения с глагольными сказуемыми — это предложения переходные
>   между простыми и сложными с разной степенью тяготения то к одним, то к
>   другим, что определяется контекстуальными условиями: Песня сбилась,
>   задрожала, разорвалась, погасла (М. Г.); Бледно-серое небо быстро
>   светлело, холодело, синело (Т.); Вставал я каждый день до восхода
>   солнца, ложился рано (Ч.).
>
> К предложениям переходного типа относятся и
>   предложения с разнооформленными сказуемыми: Она молода, изящна, любит
>   жизнь (Ч.); Я бродяга и страстно люблю жизнь (Пауст.); Вы — доктор и
>   отлично знаете, что вам вреден сырой воздух (Ч.). Предложения с
>   несколькими инфинитивами при общей для них личной или безличной форме
>   глагола являются простыми с однородными членами: Не может волк ни
>   охнуть, ни вздохнуть (Кр.). Главные члены безличных предложений
>   однородны, если объединены общей связкой: Было тихо, сумрачно и скучно
>   (М. Г.). Такие предложения часто имеют обстоятельственный или
>   объектный распространитель: В саду было тихо, прохладно (Ч.); Его
>   знобило и лихорадило (Сераф.).
>
> **Предложения определенно-личные и обобщенно-личные с
>   несколькими главными членами могут быть как простыми с однородными
>   сказуемыми, так и сложными, в целом представляя тип переходный:** Объеду
>   еще раз и, как вернусь, пойду к генералу и попрошу его (Л. Т.);
>   Глядишь и не знаешь, идет или не идет его величавая ширина (Г.); За
>   перегородкой пошептались и замолкли (Л. Т.); Ему верили, его хорошо
>   знали (А. Н. Т.)

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm

В школе, чтобы не применять термин "переходный тип", односоставные предложения с глагольным сказуемым считаются самостоятельными предложениями, ведь каждый глагол - предикативная основа, а по правилам предложения с несколькими предикативными основами считаются сложными.

Если бы был какой-то общий член, это говорило бы об одном синтаксическом месте, например, было бы так: *Сначала отыщем лодку и поплывём на другой берег*. Здесь явно один состав действующих лиц и одна ситуация по времени. В Вашем примере "***сначала*** отыщем лодку, **потом** поплывём на другой берег."  В таких предложениях даже в двусоставных  возможно выделить две предикативных основы.

Для **безличных предложений** действует валгинское **Главные члены безличных предложений однородны, если объединены общей связкой:** *Было тихо, сумрачно и скучно (М. Г.*). **Такие предложения часто имеют обстоятельственный или объектный распространитель:** *В саду было тихо, прохладно (Ч.); Его знобило и лихорадило (Сераф.).*